# Connection between Kohn-Luttinger superconductivity and Friedel oscillation

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity

The conventional way of explaining Kohn-Luttinger (KL) superconductivity (superconducting instability of electrons even when the interaction between them is purely repulsive) is by Friedel oscillations. The explanation goes something like this in 3d (three spatial dimensions):

The screened repulsive potential of a charge placed in a metal has an oscillatory part at large distances $\cos(2k_fr)/r^3$, where $k_f$ is the Fermi momentum. This behavior originates from the fact that the sharpness of the Fermi surface creates some non-analytic behavior in the dielectric function (or the particle-hole bubble). Electrons with large angular momentum (so that the radius of the pair is large) can take advantage of the negative parts of the oscillatory potential and form a pair.

This explanation is very convincing. In fact, too convincing. Looking at the 2d case, the dielectric function still has non-analytic behavior that leads to Friedel oscillations of the form $\cos(2k_fr)/r^2$. However, at least in the simple case of isotropic dispersion, there is no superconducting instability in 2d. My question is, how does the logic used to explain KL superconductivity in 3d fail in 2d?

I know that when actually calculating the particle-particle channel for superconductivity, the fact that the non-analytic behavior of the particle-hole bubble is one-sided and only occurs for momenta greater than $2k_f$ means that the system has no superconducting instability. However, I'm asking what happened to the simple explanation, as we still have Friedel oscillations in 2d.

Comment: If not supported by calculation, the Friedel oscillations "explanation" is not really an explanation, but a *hand-waving argument*. While it might provide some intuition as to why superconductivity happens even for repulsive interactions, it does not necessarily explain all the situations or have predictive value. On the math side: you could try to Fourier transform the dielectric function and see what happens at small frequencies - where it should resemble the Friedel oscillations.

Comment: I don't know superconductivity well. Could the origin simply be that in $2d$, fluctuations are larger than in $3d$ and in fact dominate re: the Mermin-Wagner theorem, and so that no mechanism at all will give a superconducting phase? Or can one get a diverging susceptibility below a BKT transition in $2d$ (and you're OK calling that superconducting), and for whatever reason one doesn't get this from Friedel oscillations in $2d$?